# Connecting Azure App Service to File Storage as network drive

Tags: azure

I have an application, which normally uses a file path to dump some data on. I want  the application to dump the data in a Azure File Storage when running in Azure, but I don't want to change the code as it is - only the configuration.

This means that I need a read/write access to a File Storage in Azure, which can be accessed through a SMB file path without any further authentication (since the app normally just dumps it on the C-drive).
I have managed to setup File Share with an SMB-path, but it requires authentication.

So, is it possible to link an App Service with a FileStorage in a way, that causes the App Service to read and write files through a normal file path (e.g. `"\\my-storage.file.core.windows.net\my-app"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Files does not support accessing it without authentication, you will need to supply a storage key to be able to access it. If it is running on a VM you could look at mapping a drive or [using cmdkey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows) to persist the credentials